# Magento: Combine eq and is null in addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento

I want to combine with OR "is null" and "eq" => array()

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attributename', array('is' => null));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attributename', array(115,116));
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use `addAttributeToFilter()` with an `OR` condition you can pass an array of arrays like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array(
            'attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_1',
            'null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'
        ),
        array(
            'attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_2',
            'in' => array(115, 116)
        )
    )
);
```

The definition of filtering against `NULL` keywords may look somewhat confusing at first glance, but it's plain simple, once you get used to it.

Magento supports two filter types of type `string`, namely `'null'` and `'notnull'`, for comparisions against `NULL` keywords.

Be aware, that even though you need to pass key=>value pairs (because an associative array is used), the value will be always ignored, when filter type `'null'` or `'notnull'` is used.

### Example

```
var_dump(
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'description',
                'null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'sku',
                'in' => array(115, 116)
            )
         )
     )
     ->getSelectSql(true)
 );
```

The output of the dump may vary depending on your shop configuration (attribute ids, count of stores, etc.), but the `OR` logic in the `WHERE` clause should always remain the same:

```
SELECT 
    `e`.*,
    IFNULL(_table_description.value, _table_description_default.value) AS `description`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `_table_description_default` ON
    (_table_description_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND
    (_table_description_default.attribute_id='57') AND
    _table_description_default.store_id=0
LEFT JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `_table_description` ON
    (_table_description.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND
    (_table_description.attribute_id='57') AND
    (_table_description.store_id='1')
WHERE (
    (IFNULL(_table_description.value, _table_description_default.value) is NULL) OR
    (e.sku in (115, 116))
)
```

Comment: Sorry, but i want filter not two different attributes... The result of your example: name_of_attribute_1 IS NULL AND (name_of_attribute_2 = 115 OR name_of_attribute_2 = 116) but i want: (name_of_attribute_1 IS null OR name_of_attribute_1 = 115 OR name_of_attribute_1 = 116). That is not possible with your code.

Comment: @timopeschka: Strange, for me it works perfectly. I added an example and its output. How does your `WHERE` clause look when executing my example?

Comment: What type of collection are you using? Some, like the flattened sales tables, have their own version of the `addAttributeToFilter` method since they are not actually EAV collections. That might explain the discrepancy you are seeing.

Comment: I was going crazy till I found your post. Thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

- I have product attribute `is_expired` with Yes and No value and i want only those product have NO value.below query work for me that get record that have neq 1 and not null.

  - Combine not equal to and null condition WITH OR.

    ```
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribue_name', array('or'=> array(
         0 => array( 'neq' => '1'),
         1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
     ), 'left');
    ```
- You can changed `neq` with `eq`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

To use addAttributeToFilter with an OR condition ***and with left join***
you can do something like that:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_1','null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'),
        array('attribute' => 'name_of_attribute_2','in' => array(115, 116))
        )
     '',
    'left'
);
```